# Rails button to approve gamer status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method like this:

gamer.rb

`def approve_gamer(type)
      where(type: type).last.update(status: 'approved')
  end`

and I want to make a button for each type to call `approve_gamer('type')`.

Should it be `button_to [:approve_gamer, gamer]` or `link_to ... class: "btn btn-default"`? How do I pass the type parameter there?

Comment: you need an action in controller to call this `approve_gamer` method which is declared in your model file

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `button_to` helper since I wouldn't call data-changing methods through GET.
`button_to` creates a form around the button and sends the data through POST.
More to read here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

You can also set the form yourself:

```
<%= form_for gamer, :url => { :action => 'approve' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field('type', :value => type_goes_here) %>
    <%= button_tag 'Approve', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
```

That method you call should be in your `gamers_controller` though.
Also you could simply call the edit method for gamer and set the parameters.

And if you call the method `approve`you have to set the route, too.